# MYSQL: How to get rows till specific month's end from very start

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project for a Fuel Pump. Here is my table for the records:
[image]

I want to display rows from very start **(2019-07-03)** till the end of the specific month **(e.g 2019-09-29)** . How could i do achieve this?

Comment: What does your code look like? What date(s) do you know already? Did you ask the user for the first (from) date? Did you ask the user for the second (to) date? What is the "very start"? Is it just all rows in the db? All rows since a certain event in the db? All rows since a certain date of th year (start of the quarter)? 2019-09-29 is not the end of September; September ends on the 30th - why do you say 29th is the end of September?

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html particularly the bit related to WHERE

Comment: @CaiusJard,  Actually i just want to display the records from the first row (date) till the specific month's end(the month would be provided by the user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `WHERE` clause will do the trick

```
SELECT id, date, total_amount, total_paid
FROM table
WHERE date <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
```

`CURDATE()` will return current date i.e. 2019-09-08

`LAST_DAY()` will return the last date of current month i.e. 2019-09-30

`WHERE` clause will return all rows with `date <= 2019-09-30`

**Update**

If you want to filter records based on user input which is month and year ( 2019-09 ) then either it can done by appending '-01' at scripting side or using `CONCAT` at MySQL level,

```
WHERE date <= LAST_DAY(CONCAT('2019-09', '-01'))
```

Comment: Makes sense, But how can i use "2019-09" (just the month and year NOT the day) in place of CURDATE().

Comment: Concat date with 01 at your script level. So 2019-09 will be converted to 2019-09-01 and substitute this in place of `CURDATE()`

Comment: Have added `MySQL` solution too in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work. You can change dates accordingly.

```
Select *
From table
Where date>='2019-07-03' AND date<='2019-09-29'
```